# Connecting to Gmail via Horde_Imap_Client

Tags: php, gmail, imap, horde

I have tried to connect to mit private as well to my google apps for work inbox via IMAP using the Horde_Imap_Client. I have used the following config:

```
$config = array(
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
    'hostspec' => 'imap.gmail.com',
    'port' => '993',
    'secure' => true,
    "debug" => "imap.log",
    "debug_literal" => true
);
```

I also tried ssl, sslv2, sslv3 and tls for the secure value. The Exception i got was `Error when communicating with the mail server.` and the imap.log only showed me this

```
------------------------------
>> Thu, 28 Jan 2016 18:29:14 +0100
>> Connection to: imap://imap.gmail.com:993/
>> Server connection took 0.0156 seconds.
>> Slow Command: 10.018 seconds
>> ERROR: read/timeout error.
------------------------------
```

I also tried allowing "insecure apps" in my google account but the result was the same. Any clues? The connection works fine with our in-house IMAP server and the office365 IMAP server

Comment: Does whereever you're running this allow port 993 through?  Have you tried basic connectivity tests?

Comment: Yes, port 993 is open and i can connect to the office365 imap server on the same port. SMTP connections to the gmail server are working too, onyl IMAP is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
'secure' => true,
```

to

```
'secure' => 'tlsv1',
```

This will force TLSv1 connections.

I ran into this same problem myself. [I posted to the Horde mailing list](https://lists.horde.org/archives/horde/Week-of-Mon-20160801/055940.html) but was able to [resolve the issue a day later](https://lists.horde.org/archives/horde/Week-of-Mon-20160801/055942.html) on my own with the above change.